# grep file for only part of line

Tags: linux, grep, extract, text-processors

I have a rtf file that I'm using grep on like this

```
 grep "Order Number" 'Extract Text Output.rtf'
```

which results in lines that look like this

```
\b\fs28 \cf2 Fab Order Number : FAB00772450\
```

and I want the result to be just FAB00772450

I know if I use -o it will just return the word "Order Number" but that doesn't help me

Comment: Is not the same as this http://stackoverflow.com/q/974757/422353?

Comment: how the hell is this question off topic ? someone please explain

Comment: Try piping that to awk, then you can split it up and do whatever you like to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat 'Extract Text Output.rtf' | sed -n 's/Order Number : \(.*\)\\/\1/gp'
```

Yields exactly what you want.

Explanation:

- `sed -n` suppress default output of sed
- `s/.../.../g` search and replace, g: everything/globally
- `Order Number : \(.*\)\\` look for "`Order Number :` " string and a `backslash` and save anything in between to group 1; (downside of using sed is to have to escape regex's grouping operator: `(...)` with `\(...\)` )
- `\1` use group 1 as replacement
- `p` print replacement if any match

This is way more flexible and generic than using hard-coded awk groups ($7).

Note 1: use .*? if you have lines formatted like this:

```
 \cf2 Fab Order Number : FAB00772450\ \b \cf2
```

This prevents regex from being greedy and stops at the first backslash. Not tested if sed supports *? and +? operators, but let's hope.

Note 2: If you have multiple parts you want to extract from a line, use multiple groups and in the replacement string you can even switch them with formatting, like `.../\2 - \1/`

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
grep "Order Number" test.txt | awk {'print $7'} | tr "\\\ " " "
```

output:

FAB00772450

Comment: what does the 7 do ?

Comment: it prints the 7th column I think. It splits on whitespace.

Comment: It prints the 7th field.  The split is on whatever FS is (defaults to space).

Comment: That's not a very flexible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is a better and cleaner approach than any of the previous answers:

`grep -oP 'Order Number :\s*\K[^\r\n]*' 'Extract Text Output.rtf'`

or

`grep -oP 'Order Number :\s*\K[A-Z0-9]*' 'Extract Text Output.rtf'`

- `\K` discards anything that was matched up until that point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If this format is always followed but the number of tokens is not always the same, you could pipe it through something like

sed 's/.*: //'  | sed 's#\##'

This also yields "FAB00772450"